# How do I split data into 4 groups with even amounts of time?

Tags: r, if-statement, split

This data frame is a result of a video analysis of 11 subjects under 2 separate conditions: vigil vs. video. I have start and stop columns where time is measured in seconds. I grouped the data frame by subject(sbj) and cognitive load (condition) and then found the amount of time of each video by subtracting the last stop time and first start time of each subject for each condition. I then divided the overall time of the video by 4 to see how long each quartile would be (in seconds). Here is an example of what the data looks like, although my actual data is a bit more complex:

```
library(dplyr)
start <- c(35, 44, 53, 62, 71, 80)
stop <- c(42, 50, 59, 70, 77, 85)
condition <- c('video', 'vigil', 'video', 'vigil', 'video', 'vigil')
sbj <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
df <- data.frame(start, stop, condition, sbj)
df1 <- group_by(df, sbj, condition)
df2 <- summarize(df1, time = last(stop)-first(start))
hd2 <- transform(df2, quartile = time/4)
hd3 <- inner_join(df1, hd2)
hd3
 start stop condition sbj time quartile
1    35   42     video   1    7     1.75
2    44   50     vigil   1    6     1.50
3    53   59     video   2    6     1.50
4    62   70     vigil   2    8     2.00
5    71   77     video   3    6     1.50
6    80   85     vigil   3    5     1.25
```

I would like to split the data into 4 groups, where each group equals the length of 1/4 of the overall video time (the quartile). Since the start of each video is not at 0 seconds (for subject 1 you can see it starts at 35 seconds), I need to add the first start value for each subject under each condition to the value of the quartile to get the appropriate time for 1/4 of the overall video. I tried an ifelse statement, but the resulting answer splits up the quartiles very roughly.

```
attach(hd3)
fx <- first(start) + quartile
hd3$Q <- with(hd3, ifelse(start <= fx, 1, 
ifelse(start <= fx * 2, 2, 
ifelse(start <= fx * 3, 3,
ifelse(start <= fx * 4, 4)))))
```

I'm hoping someone can suggest a way to split up the quartiles more elegantly and correctly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've edited my answer, and providing tested code now.

The data that you provide should have multiple rows per `condition` and `sbj` for the results to be interesting.

```
library(dplyr)

start <- c(35, 44, 53, 62, 71, 80, 87, 90)
stop <- c(42, 50, 59, 70, 77, 85, 89, 95)
condition <- c('video', 'vigil', 'video', 'vigil', 'video', 'vigil', 'video', 'vigil')
sbj <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(start, stop, condition, sbj)
df1 <- group_by(df, sbj, condition)

df1$med <- with(df1, (start + stop)/2)
df4 <- summarize(df1, 
  min = first(start), 
  range = last(stop)-first(start)
  )
hd4 <- inner_join(df1, df4)
hd4$quant <- with(hd4, (med-min)/range)
hd4$group <-  cut(hd4$quant, breaks=seq(0, 1, length=5), 
  include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help; I added an example data set to make things easier; sorry I didn't have it there initially!

Comment: Check out edited answer, and see if it works for your real data.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more correct and concise than the way I was trying it.